# Read NetworkStream into an Array

Tags: arrays, networking, tcp

I have been trying to read a networkstream into an array. The code below works fine but is very slow:

```
Private Function ReadBytes(ByVal NetworkStream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream) As Byte()
Dim Bytes As Byte() = {}
Dim Index As Integer = 0

While NetworkStream.DataAvailable = True
    Array.Resize(Bytes, Index + 1)
    Bytes(Index) = NetworkStream.ReadByte()
    Index += 1
End While

Return Bytes
```

End Function

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is each time the array is resized the array is actually being copied as well. This code should solve your problem:

```
Private Function ReadBytes(ByVal NetworkStream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream) As Byte()
    Dim BlockSize As Integer = 65536
    Dim Bytes(BlockSize) As Byte
    Dim Position As Integer = 0
    Dim DataRead As Integer = 0

    Do
        ReDim Preserve Bytes(Position + BlockSize)

        DataRead = NetworkStream.Read(Bytes, Position, BlockSize)
        Position += BlockSize

        If DataRead = 0 Then
            For i = Bytes.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If Not Bytes(i) = 0 Then
                    ReDim Preserve Bytes(i)
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Next
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Return Bytes
End Function
```